# Is there a word that means "nearly synonymous"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Google was no help. It found many synonyms for almost, nearly, close, etc. Is there a noun that means "not quite a synonym"?

Examples:

car : wagon

hide : lose

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between partial and total synonyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94972/what-is-the-difference-between-partial-and-total-synonyms)

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103850/are-there-by-chance-any-synonyms-for-synonym

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **parasynonym**?

> parasynonym (plural parasynonyms)
>
> (linguistics) A word or phrase that shares similar meanings with another term in some > contexts, but not all; a close synonym.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parasynonym

Comment: There is no difference between the (first) definition of this word given above, and a meaningful definition of **synonym** itself. There are no two words (other than alternative spellings) that 'share exactly similar meanings in all contexts'. I use 'near-synonym' to mean a word 'almost interchangeable with a second word in some senses with no vast change of meaning' (eg 'He made some judicious/prudent investments') and 'synonym' to mean a word 'interchangeable in some senses with a second word with no or very little discernible change of meaning' (eg 'He gave a contented/satisfied smile).

Comment: I'm not sure about true synonymy myself, but English is full of words of different linguistic origins that essentially mean the same thing (kingly/regal, paternal/fatherly, etc.). I suspect that this word was coined by someone who does believe in true synonymy.

Answer (score 4):

**Similar** means "resembling without being identical", but I imagine you're looking for something fancier.

Some dictionaries think **synonymous** itself will work:

> adjective: synonymous (of a word or phrase) having the same or nearly the same meaning as another word or phrase in the same language

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking more for something that describes a word. So "X" where X is an X of synonym.

Comment: This definition is more sensible than many, but still omits the necessary 'in certain usages'. A satisfied customer. a contented customer. A contented cow, a satisfied cow???

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like the word **like** or **alike**?

Comment: Sort of, but more like a synonym for "not quite a synonym." I may need to rephrase the question because the word should be a noun.